# How do I make the view controller navigator thing go away?

Tags: xcode

I am working in Xcode 13.1 and I have a small version of my view controller hovering above the view controller I am working on.  It appears to be a way to auto-focus my actual view controller window on a specific portion of the view controller, but in actuality it is just in my way.  Is there a way to toggle off this feature?  I can't figure out what it's called, but here is a picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcE4J.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called mini map. You can disable the mini map by clicking the storyboard options.
[image]

Comment: Bless you.  That was driving me insane.  Thanks.